# My divs do not float to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that has probably been asked over here a gazillion times. I am creating a slideshow and accordingly want my divs to be stacked side by side.

Here is the semantic structure:

```
<section class = "slideshow">
   <div class = "slides">
       <div class = "slideholder>
          <div id = "slide_1" class = "slide">  
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class = "slideholder >
          <div id = "slide_2" class = "slide">  
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class = "slideholder>
          <div id = "slide_3" class = "slide">  
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

The corresponding CSS looks like this :

```
.slides{
position:relative;
margin:2% auto;
width:80%;
max-height:300px;
}

.slideshow{
position:relative;
margin:100px auto;
width:100%;
min-height:80%;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.slideholder{
width:100%;
min-height:300px;
position:relative;
}

.slide{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}

.slide div{
 min-height:300px;
}
```

You may ask why slide div is separately styled from slide. Well, the class slide has a couple of divs inside it that are styled in a particular way. The min-height only captures one feature of that, the rest is with animations so probably doesn't hold any importance to the context of this question.

I put float:left  style in .slide div as well as .slides div. I am a little confused why it still renders as block elements vertically than horizontally as I want them to be instead. Can anyone teach me how to fish ?

THanks

Comment: in the first place please remove the spaces surrounding `=`, also slide 1 and 3 are missing the closing double quotes on `class="slideholder>`

Comment: cool, that is a typo error here and not in the code, I'll edit it, but really that won't solve this problem

Comment: I see you have each slide's `width` set to `100%`. Do you want it to float-left beyond the browser screen width? If so, `float` is not the way to go.

Comment: I guess I do want it to float beyond the browser screen coz at any given point I am looking to only have one slide shown in ...will be having overflow:hidden specified at some point.

Comment: Well, you should not be using `float`, then. You may want to `fixed` or `absolute` positioning.

Comment: ummm, they are all have absolute positioning, but they stack  vertically below each other, I want them to stack horizontally next to each other

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute positioning and set the left to minus whatever works(enough to take the image out of sight)

```
.slides {
position:absolute;
left:-400px;
}
```

something like that